# Disabling user interaction for the Google Earth plugin

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin, user-interaction

I'm putting together an app that will show a news item's location in Google Earth using the javascript api. This is working great but we want to prevent users from manually dragging the globe around.

I know for Google Maps there is a function disableDragging which accomplishes this, but in the Earth api I could find no similar function.

I also tried placing a (nearly) transparent div over the GE container but any div with a non-solid background disappears over the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a standard method in the Api to disable mouse control of the globe.

```
// where ge is an instance of the plugin object 
ge.getOptions().setMouseNavigationEnabled(false);
```

Here is a [working example](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/options/index.html).

I am not 100% sure what you mean with 'transparent div over the GE container' but perhaps the [iframe shim technique](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/customcontrols/index.html) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for! And yeah I ended up using the frame shims but this is much better. Thanks again!